# need example a Riemann-integrable function is not continuous

Tags: integration

[image: I cant find example in 7.32]

every continuous function is Riemann integrable,continuity is certainly not necessary.

I dont know anything about measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $f$ to be identically $0$ on $\Bbb{R}$, except that $f(0) = 1$. To see that this is Riemann integrable, note that the lower sums are all $0$ (suppose we're integrating on $[-1, 1]$, for clarity). But the upper sums can be made arbitrary small, by choosing small intervals around $0$.

---

More generally, $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of points of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure $0$; so something like [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), which is discontinuous on $\Bbb{Q}$ is still Riemann-integrable.